# How to change or auto increment value of text box after selecting value from drop down?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i am working on project of asp.net and sql in which we assign auto generated membership number. Currently there are two membership types "APFA" and "FPFA" (which is selected from drop down) the member num has reached to series 6735.
now there is new member type "PFA" which is required to start from "0000" on same web form.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="memtype" runat="server" class="label" Height="24px" Width="130px"></asp:DropDownList> 
    </td>
  <td colspan="7" align="right">
       <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" class="text" Text="MemberShip Number:" 
           Width="149px"></asp:Label>
  </td>  
   <td align="left">
       <asp:Label ID="memberno" class="label" runat="server" Font-Size="Large" 
           Width="71px"></asp:Label>
```

and cs code:

```
memberno.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(obj.MemNo()) + 1);
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: You COULD update this value using javascript, onchange events etc. but assigning newIds in this fashion rings big alarm bells for me.

I really think the membershipId should be returned to them via the server.

Comment: One workaround can be using a table named mem_no and its columns as APFA, FPFA, PFA (type number). Keep the last ID numbers in the respective columns and when adding a member, query the last ID number as well as update it.

Comment: @jomsk1e the problem is how can i  reset the value of member number on selection from dropdown as APFA has series in continuous where as new type "FPA" have to start with 0001.

Comment: @SohamBanerjee there is already a table as you suggested. Can you provide query for this updation?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using javascript:

```
<script>
    var selected = document.getElementById('<%= memtype.ClientID %>').val();
    var label = document.getElementById('%= memberno.ClientID %>');

    //change the value here depending on your conditions
    label.value = 'any value';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late reply, here's the table design and update statement:-
Let the table(named mem_no) columns be APFA, FPFA, PFA (type number).

Let's say user selects APFA:-

```
    --select query--
    SELECT APFA from mem_no;

    --update statement--
    UPDATE mem_no SET APFA=APFA+1;
```